# External monitor not working via USB C

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, usb-c

The external monitor was working until a recent update from Ubuntu. I am running this through an HP dock. The mouse and keyboard work. My system can see the device, but signal is not getting to it.

```
Operating System: Ubuntu 23.04                    
          Kernel: Linux 6.2.0-20-generic
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: System76
  Hardware Model: Pangolin
Firmware Version: ARB928_V00.01_T0025ASY1_ms
```

```
xrandr --listactivemonitors
Monitors: 2
 0: +*XWAYLAND0 1920/340x1080/190+0+0  XWAYLAND0
 1: +XWAYLAND6 1920/530x1080/300+0+0  XWAYLAND6
```

```
-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: AMD Ryzen 7 6800U with Radeon Graphics
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
```

Any help would be appreciated!